# Is it useful to do an MBA after PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, masters, business-school

I have heard of people who have gone on to pursue an MBA after their doctorates. What are the advantages/downsides of this?

Wouldn't the companies recruiting them after MBA value their doctorate experience less compared to the experience gained at an MNC? Is there a risk of them being valued as "failed" doctorates?

Comment: MBAs and PhDs are two different things. If you want to run a business, do an MBA.

Comment: It really depends on the degree and what you ultimately intend to do... What do you plan to get your PhD in, and how do you plan to use an MBA as part of your future plans?

Comment: Nature just had an article about it: http://www.nature.com/naturejobs/science/articles/10.1038/nj7523-523a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several cases where PhDs do an MBA. Some of them are:

1. Bored of research as a whole.
2. Irritation with academia and poor scope in Industry.
3. Want to earn money.
4. For furthering responsibilities at the university where one is a professor. If you do some looking around, a high amount of Deans to have an MBA along with a PhD.

Answer (score 1):

No degree ever goes waste. Most people with PhD and MBA acquire director positions in companies.

Comment: "no degree ever goes waste" [citation needed]

Comment: "Most people with PhD and MBA acquire director positions in companies." That seems insanely hard to believe.

Answer (score 1):

A qualification regardless of level and field of study is never a waste, one needs to realize how to use it wisely and appropriately. As we navigate life we shift perspective and interests, our education choices therefore need to reflect this. Ph.D provides sound research focus, MBA provides sound business and leadership focus. The two combined is a great and electrifying combination.

Comment: _A qualification regardless of level and field of study is never a waste_ — [citation needed]

Comment: @JeffE I can indeed think of many examples where a qualification was indeed a waste. However, a (good) MBA is not usually one of those cases.

Comment: Right.  A **good** MBA is not one of those cases.  But many (if not _most_) MBAs are not **good**.

Answer (score 1):

PhD = specialist in a subject, research skills, critical mind
MBA = Broad generalist, management, problem solving

The focus and scope is not the same. 
Also like it was said most researchers who want to climb the ladder need to take the management track which often require an MBA. Put simply an MD is an MD but a hospital manager needs to be an MD and MBA.

Also to teach at a business school other than math or economics you normally need an MBA. Best is a Phd/MBA but while a lowly MBA can teach that is not usually the case for a PhD.

Comment: If a person is smart they will market their experience during the acquisition of their PhD as also providing them with the problem solving and management skill sets. If you are going to be successful in research or business these are good things to have.